# Sub menus in nav bar link in material ui

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, material-ui, react-router-dom

Hi I am new to react and wanted to implement sub menus to my menu.

What I wanted was something like this  Report > My report
> MIS report

I am importing and using NavLink from react router dom.

The menu currently looks like this with no sub-menus:

[image]

This is my code where I am using the nav bar link:

```
export const mainListItems = (
  <List>
    <NavLink to="dashboard">
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
      </ListItem>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to="userform">
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Registration" />
      </ListItem>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to="">
      <ListItem button>
        <ListItemIcon></ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Report" />
      </ListItem>
    </NavLink>
  </List>
);
```

This is the link in my App.js

```
const App = () => (
  <HashRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/userform" component={UserForm} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />

      <Redirect from="/" to="signin" />
    </Switch>
  </HashRouter>
);
```

I need some direction in this. How do I implement my own sub menus

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Nested List Items](https://material-ui.com/components/lists/#nested-list) and you can find a similar example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5mm47?file=/demo.js).

[image: screenshot nested list example]

Comment: Can you share that example in a class component